# Understanding a metric inequality in a proof about discontinuities

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Let $(X,d)$ be some metric space and $f: \mathbb{R}\rightarrow X$ be a function where all one-sided limits exist. Fix an $\epsilon >0$ and a $s$ and suppose that $$d(\lim\limits_{x\downarrow s}f(x),f(s))\geq\epsilon/2\space\space (\star).$$

It is then claimed that there is an $u\in(s,s+1/n)$ (where $n$ is fixed) such that $d(\lim\limits_{x\downarrow s}f(x),f(u))<\epsilon/4$

I am having seeing why the claim is true. I did the obvious and supposed that, $d(\lim\limits_{x\downarrow s}f(x),f(u))\geq\epsilon/4$, for every $u\in(s,s+1/n)$, and tried to use $(\star)$ to get a contradiction but get nowhere.

So I would appreciate any help to show me why the claim is true. This claim is from a proof that functions with one-sided limits cannot have large discontinuities that accumulate, .i.e $$(\forall t)(\forall\epsilon>0)(\exists\delta>0)(\forall s)(0<|t-s|<\delta\Rightarrow d(\lim\limits_{x\downarrow s}f(x),f(s))+d(f(s),\lim\limits_{x\uparrow s}f(x))<\epsilon).$$
So if you have any other proofs of this fact please let me know. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The claim is not related to the condition $(\star)$, but instead follows directly from the definition of limit.

Since the limit is assumed to exist, for any $\epsilon>0$ there exists a $\delta>0$ such that for any $s<u<s+\delta$, $d(\lim_{x\to s+}f(x),f(u))<\epsilon$. So in particular for the desired bound $\epsilon/4$ one can find a $\delta$ and then pick any $u>s$ that is smaller than both $s+\delta$ and $s+1/n$.

Comment: Thanks, needed a fresh pair of eyes to see this which I see know is plainly obvious.